# Can't add a PFX to Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I generated pfx certificate using the following script:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -nodes -keyout security.key -out security.crt -subj "/CN=ourdomain.com" -days 3650
openssl pkcs12 -export -out security.pfx -inkey security.key -in security.crt -certfile security.crt
```

Next, i'm trying to add this certificate into our Azure Key Vault (into certificates section). After using this command:

> $cer = Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $vaultName -Name
>   $certificateName -FilePath 'security.pfx' -Password $securepfxpwd

i get the following error:

> Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate : Private key is present in more than
>   one item in certificate collection

This certificate is successfully used by our application and doesn't throw any errors in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you could generate a key as `.pem` file instead of `.key` file then convert PEM to PFX, try the following commands:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -nodes -keyout security.pem -out security.crt -subj "/CN=ourdomain.com" -days 3650
openssl pkcs12 -export -out security.pfx -inkey security.pem -in security.crt
```

This works on my side:

[image]

Details from [Importing Certificates to Key Vault](https://www.noelbundick.com/posts/importing-certificates-to-key-vault/)

Comment: it does work indeed. Thank you very much for your help, Nancy.